# Shuffling with constraints on pairs

Tags: python, shuffle

I have `n` lists each of length `m`. assume `n*m` is even. i want to get a randomly shuffled list with all elements, under the constraint that the elements in locations `i,i+1` where `i=0,2,...,n*m-2` never come from the same list. edit: other than this constraint i do not want to bias the distribution of random lists. that is, the solution should be equivalent to a complete random choice that is reshuffled until the constraint hold.

example:

list1: a1,a2

list2: b1,b2

list3: c1,c2

allowed: b1,c1,c2,a2,a1,b2

disallowed: b1,c1,c2,b2,a1,a2

Comment: Why not just reshuffle until the constraints are satisfied? I think the probability to satisfy them all is at least 1/e for large n (because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Limit_of_ratio_of_derangement_to_permutation_as_n_approaches_%E2%88%9E)

Comment: this seems to take exponential time in the length of the list...

Comment: Yes, sorry, for some reason I decided that m is always 2.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to think of your number set as n chunks of item, each chunk having the length of m. If you randomly select for each chunk exactly one item from each lists, then you will never hit dead ends. Just make sure that the first item in each chunk (except the first chunk) will be of different list than the last element of the previous chunk.

You can also iteratively randomize numbers, always making sure you pick from a different list than the previous number, but then you can hit some dead ends.

Finally, another possible solution is to randomize a number on each position sequentially, but only from those which "can be put there", that is, if you put a number, none of the constraints will be violated, that is, you will have at least a possible solution.

Comment: option b is not good due to dead ends. option a i think skews the distribution more than the constraint requires. i edited my question to emphasize this point. option c - not sure how it differs from b

Comment: @eyaler Option C is actually a smart version of option B. while with option B you are randomizing from what is possible currently (on each iteration), with option C you do not let the program to choose an item if it means that the problem is no longer solvable (for instance the last item from list X, when only list Y has elements not yet chosen, at least two).

Answer (score 1):

A variation of b above that avoids dead ends: At each step you choose twice. First, randomly chose an item. Second, randomly choose where to place it. At the Kth step there are k optional places to put the item (the new item can be injected between two existing items). Naturally, you only choose from allowed places.
Money!

Comment: How do you guarantee that the constraints are satisfied?

Comment: The place to add the new item is chosen only from allowed places so no violation can happen when injecting it to its new place

Comment: Then it won't be a uniformly random distribution. Violation which happened at some moment can disappear later.

Comment: nice! some questions and comments: 1. instead of randomly selecting where to put the item. can we first try to put it in the last location? or alternatively can we always insert it in the first allowed location? or would these methods create any bias? 2. do you choose an item from a list different from the previous one? we would need to relax this behavior once there is only one list left. if we do not change lists each time we could have not legit placement and need to resample 3. actually even if you change lists each time you can still get to no legit insertion: abbccaa and next item is a

Comment: 4. when having an odd number of items in the solution being constructed, there are two ways to do the pairing (remainder at the start or end). should i always use a certain one or is there a case for switching?

Comment: 5. i think the innovation for me here is using insertion as a strong method for fixing problems. however this means that i need to recalculate the legitimacy of all items after the insertion point each time. the second innovation for me is building it sample by sample which makes the fixing easier, however i wonder whether the requirement that each step is legitimate can block paths to certain legit states

Answer (score 1):

1. arrange your lists into a list of lists
2. save each item in the list as a tuple with the list index in the list of lists
3. loop n*m times
4. on even turns - flatten into one list and just rand pop - yield the item and the item group
5. on odd turns - temporarily remove the last item group and pop as before - in the end add the removed group back

#### important - how to avoid deadlocks?

a deadlock can occur if all the remaining items are from one group only.
to avoid that, check in each iteration the lengths of all the lists
and **check if the longest list is longer than the sum of all the others**.
**if true** - pull for that list

that way you are never left with only one list full

---

here's a gist with an attempt to solve this in python
https://gist.github.com/YontiLevin/bd32815a0ec62b920bed214921a96c9d

Answer (score 0):

A very quick and simple method i am trying is:

```
random shuffle
loop over the pairs in the list:
   if pair is bad:
   loop over the pairs in the list:
      if both elements of the new pair are different than the bad pair:
         swap the second elements
         break
```

will this always find a solution? will the solutions have the same distribution as naive shuffling until finding a legit solution?